# UIImageView: get transformed UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-graphics, transform

I'm rotating UIImageView using this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
myImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle*M_PI/180);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now I want to get rotated image. Can I do this? I was trying to make it with CoreGraphics using CGImageRotatedByAngle function from accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191492/rotate-image-in-uiimageview) but it transforms coordinates slighlty incorrect (finally we get third screenshot marked as wrong). As you can see the image loses its original size and is cropped. My goal is to get image like on central shot with original size and rotated for specified angle. I mean it's required that the size of rotated shape stay unchanged but new image of course is gonna be larger than initial.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I'm answering my own question again, hopefully it will be useful for somebody in future...
Coming back to CGImageRotatedByAngle as I previously said it gives almost required effect but coordinate system translation sequence must be slighly altered. And here is the way I got the desired result:

```
- (CGImageRef)CGImageRotatedByAngle:(CGImageRef)imgRef angle:(CGFloat)angle {

    CGFloat angleInRadians = angle * (M_PI / 180);
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
    CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, transform);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                   rotatedRect.size.width,
                                                   rotatedRect.size.height,
                                                   8,
                                                   0,
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(bmContext, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(bmContext, YES);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bmContext, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextTranslateCTM( bmContext, 0.5f * rotatedRect.size.width, 0.5f * rotatedRect.size.height ) ;
    CGContextRotateCTM(bmContext, angleInRadians);
    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, CGRectMake(-imgRect.size.width* 0.5f, -imgRect.size.height * 0.5f,
                                             imgRect.size.width,
                                             imgRect.size.height),
                       imgRef);
    CGImageRef rotatedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
    CFRelease(bmContext);
    [(id)rotatedImage autorelease];

    return rotatedImage;
}
```

Comment: Don't feel bad about answering your own question. Feel free to go ahead and accept the answer if it provides an accurate, relevant answer to the question. See [this wiki post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Answer (score 0):

it works for me , and another way to solve

```
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, transform);
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedRect.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedRect.size);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is swift 4.1 version of **heximal**'s answer.

```
extension CGImage {

    func rotated(by angle: CGFloat) -> CGImage? {
        let angleInRadians = angle * .pi / 180

        let imgRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: angleInRadians)
        let rotatedRect = imgRect.applying(transform)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        guard let bmContext = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: Int(rotatedRect.size.width),
            height: Int(rotatedRect.size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: 0,
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
            else {
                return nil
        }

        bmContext.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
        bmContext.setShouldAntialias(true)
        bmContext.interpolationQuality = .high
        bmContext.translateBy(x: rotatedRect.size.width * 0.5, y: rotatedRect.size.height * 0.5)
        bmContext.rotate(by: angleInRadians)
        let drawRect = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: -imgRect.size.width * 0.5, y: -imgRect.size.height * 0.5),
            size: imgRect.size)
        bmContext.draw(self, in: drawRect)

        guard let rotatedImage = bmContext.makeImage() else { return nil }

        return rotatedImage
    }

}
```