# Rotate a image (not UIImageView) by one degree each time when a button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

There are several post that I've found but none of them are useful for me.

I want to rotate a image (either clockwise/anti-clockwise at a time). I've done this by following code but when I assign a rotated image to a image view then image become smaller after every click.

I've debugged and found that at every rotation (either clockwise/anti-clockwise) image size is increased. I know when image is rotated then image size is little bit increased but here image size is increased much grater than expectation.

```
//code for image rotation
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(UIImage*)oldImage deg:(CGFloat)degrees{

// calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height)];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
// Create the bitmap context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

//   // Rotate the image context
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, (degrees * M_PI / 180));

// Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-oldImage.size.width / 2, -oldImage.size.height / 2, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height), [oldImage CGImage]);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}


- (IBAction)btnRotateImageTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

static NSInteger degree = 0;

if (sender.tag == 471) { //rotate left btn tag
    degree += 1;
} else if (sender.tag == 472) { //rotate right btn tag
    degree += -1;
}

UIImage *img = [self imageRotatedByDegrees:self.imgViewTeethTemplate.image deg:degree];
self.imgViewTeethTemplate.image = img;

}
```

I don't know is this right way or not. If not can anyone help me out of this. Any help is must appreciated.

Comment: may be [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219855/uiimageview-get-transformed-uiimage) would be helpful to you

Comment: I thing is not the image that become smaller. When you rotate the image, the canvas of the image change to keep image size. An image rotate to 45° can't fit in the canvas of an image without rotation. So you have to update the UIImageView frame.

Comment: I tried to update the image view frame but every time I'm getting bigger size...and at end it goes beyond screen.

Comment: *nothing related to question :* doesn't `degree += -1;` should be `degree -= 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are calculating the new size at each rotation. You should copy your image into a new one that is 1/cos(45deg) larger, (that is 2/sqrt(2)) and then do the rotations of this new image as required. You do not need to worry about loosing part of your original image as it will be contained in the larger one whatever the rotation is.